# Mysql Select from multiple row, except Null in columns, result: latest in one row

Tags: mysql, select

Im struggle with selection for a view in MySql.
The sensors inserts data in 3 type of rows. Nothing(null), gpsdata+lqi+null and temperature+battery+null.
Now i need a queryt to show latest data/deviceid in one row.

table: data

```
id  deviceid    timestamp          temp gpslat  gpslng  lqi     battery
1   12C79E6     2019-11-18 19:49:30                                         (all Null)
2   12C79E6     2019-11-18 19:49:29     59.xxx  18.xxx  Good                (gpsdata+lqi)
3   3BB3F7      2019-11-18 19:49:28 20                          2.1         (temp+battery)
4   3BB3F7      2019-11-18 19:49:27     59.xxx  18.xxx  Exelent
5   12C79E6     2019-11-18 19:49:26 8                           2.9
6   12C79E6     2019-11-18 19:49:25     59.xxx  18.xxx  Good    
7   12C79E6     2019-11-18 19:49:24 8               2.9
8   12C79E6     2019-11-18 19:49:23     59.xxx  18.xxx  Good
```

Timestamp set by DB when insert, id=index

Result
show: latest timestamp for the deviceid, latest temp, latest lat+lnggps, latest lgi, latest battery for all deviceid,one row/deviceid

```
1   12C79E6     2019-11-18 19:49:30 8   59.335xxx   18.033xxx   Good    2.9 
2   3BB3F7      2019-11-18 19:49:28 20  59.335xxx   18.033xxx   Exelent 2.1
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: what if the max timestamp per deviceid is tied (has equal values) in two or more records... Also which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Its not possible to have equal values in timestamp per device. The device cant report that way. Version of MySQL is 10.2.26-MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly... By you could use a series of inline queries:

```
select 
    d.id,
    d.deviceid,
    (select max(d1.timestamp) from data d1 where d1.deviceid = d.deviceid) timestamp,
    (
        select d1.temp 
        from data d1 
        where 
            d1.deviceid = d.deviceid 
            and d1.temp is not null
        order by d1.timestamp desc
        limit 1
    ) temp,
    (
        select d1.gpslat
        from data d1 
        where 
            d1.deviceid = d.deviceid 
            and d1.gpslat is not null
        order by d1.timestamp desc
        limit 1
    ) gpslat,
    (
        select d1.gpslng 
        from data d1 
        where 
            d1.deviceid = d.deviceid 
            and d1.gpslng is not null
        order by d1.timestamp desc
        limit 1
    ) gpslng,
    (
        select d1.lqi 
        from data d1 
        where 
            d1.deviceid = d.deviceid 
            and d1.lqi is not null
        order by d1.timestamp desc
        limit 1
    ) lqi,
    (
        select d1.battery 
        from data d1 
        where 
            d1.deviceid = d.deviceid 
            and d1.battery is not null
        order by d1.timestamp desc
        limit 1
    ) battery
from (select deviceid, min(id) id from data group by deviceid) d
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7253190785055e9978427f03c2b0bc3b)**:

```
id | deviceid | timestamp           | temp | gpslat | gpslng | lqi     | battery
-: | :------- | :------------------ | ---: | :----- | :----- | :------ | ------:
 1 | 12C79E6  | 2019-11-18 19:49:30 |    8 | 59.xxx | 18.xxx | Good    |     2.9
 3 | 3BB3F7   | 2019-11-18 19:49:28 |   20 | 59.xxx | 18.xxx | Exelent |     2.1
```